# No Database Selected Error in PHP myAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL statement:

`DELETE FROM Menu WHERE restaurantID = '2' AND foodID = '12';`

And I keep getting the error "#1046 - No database selected" whenever I try to run it. I looked up example SQL statements on W3 Schools and it seems like my statement has all the necessary parts.

Comment: It is part of a PHP file. Here is the code:

`else if(isSet($_POST['removeItem']))
 {
  $RemoveFromMenu = "DELETE FROM Menu WHERE restaurantID = '$restaurantID' AND foodID = '$foodItem'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $RemoveFromMenu);

 }`

Comment: I thought it was PHPMyAdmin? If not, edit your question to include the PHP code and change your title.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM your_database_name.Menu WHERE restaurantID = '2' AND foodID = '12';
```

Comment: How would I do that in a in PHP? This is part of a larger project.

Comment: you should use php pdo interface for that

Answer (score 0):

this code can help you to interact with mysql and php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "UserName","password", "databaseName");
$sql="delete from Table_name where restaurantID = '2' AND foodID = '12' ";

$del = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    mysqli_close($link);
    if ($del) {
        echo "deleted ";
    } else {
        echo "did not delete ";
    }
```

Notice : that you run the server .
for your problem as I think You did not select the database
forget about that use the above code it is very simple.
I hope I cloud help you.
good luck